# Show list of tuples as a tree / graph

Tags: networking, graph, tuples, mininet

Is there any tool that enables me to input a list of tuples and that shows me a graph that represents the tuples?

Example:

```
(root,a), (root,b), (b,c), (b,d)
```

This would be a Tree that looks like that

```
     root
     /  \
     a   b
       /  \
      c    d
```

I need this to verify that the topology of a network I created in mininet really looks like I want. It has about 1000 links and it is not possible to check that manually without a visualisation.

I does not matter if it is an online tool, a python script, a command line tool or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Gephi works fine!